# RabbitMQ delivery acknowledgement timeout workarounds: pika or editing RabbitMQ configuration file for Amazon-MQ managed cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, pika, rabbitmqctl, amazon-mq

**Background:** Recent changes to RabbitMQ 3.8.x have created a [delivery acknowledgement timeout](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout) of 30 minutes. According to the documents, this can be overridden in the rabbitmq.conf file by setting a consumer_timeout value.

**My issue:** I am using the pika client library and need more than 30 minutes to process each message in my work queue. I am using a managed RabbitMQ cluster through AWS Amazon-MQ and had no issues until a few days ago, but now receive `PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgment on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms` messages in my logs. My cluster is set up for automated minor version updates, so that's my assumption of how these changes occurred.

I understand that the point of a managed service is to hide all of these setup details from the user, but of course, now I need to change one of them. I've found that I can communicate with the remote cluster via the rabbitmqadmin CLI to perform tasks like listing queues, but I am still searching for a way to remotely edit the underlying configuration file. The only information I have for my cluster is the host (in form of *b-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com*), username, and password. Does anyone know if this is possible? I'm new to the various CLI tools such as rabbitmqctl and rabbitmq-diagnostics so any help would be appreciated.

Is there any way to set the consumer_timeout value through the library or a similar workaround for pika users? I was hoping that there might be an argument to the Channel.basic_consume() function, but I also understand that this may be a cluster setting rather than something that can be set through the consumer.

First-time question asker here so I greatly appreciate any assistance and feedback on whether I've provided enough information.

Comment: I started to suffer from this same issue. will appreciate a solution.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can now set the `consumer_timeout` value through configuration in Amazon MQ. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/07/amazon-mq-managed-configuration-rabbitmq-brokers/

Here's a guide for how to apply configuration to your Amazon MQ broker. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/rmq-configuration.html

Starting in RabbitMQ version 3.12 you can also set the delivery acknowledgement timeout with a policy. https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout